# tkinter: clear inheritanced widget

Tags: python, tkinter

how to remove the page1's widgets when the next button is pressed, so that only the page2's widgets is shown.

and vice versa if the back button is pressed on page 2, so the widgets don't overlap

```
from tkinter import *

class Buttons(Button):
    def __init__(self,master,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master=master,**kwargs)
        self.look = {"fg":"ghost white","bg":"DarkBlue"}
        self.config(self.look)

    def makeButton(self,name,texts,wide,rows,cols,com):
        self.name = name
        self.texts = texts
        self.wide = wide
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.com = com
        self.name = Buttons(root,text=self.texts,width=self.wide,command=self.com)
        self.name.place(x=self.rows,y=self.cols)

class make(Buttons):
    def __init__(self, mainFrame):
        super().__init__(mainFrame) 
        self.main_frame = Frame(mainFrame, width=400, height=300)
        self.main_frame.place()
        self.page1()

    def page1(self):
        self.makeButton("name1","Page1-widgets1",15,125,30,None)
        self.makeButton("name2","Page1-widgets2",15,125,80,None)
        self.makeButton("name3","Next",15,125,130,self.page2)
        self.makeButton("name4","Exit",15,125,180,exit)

    def page2(self):
        self.makeButton("name5","Page2-widgets1",15,135,40,None)
        self.makeButton("name6","Page2-widgets2",15,135,90,None)
        self.makeButton("name7","Page2-widgets3",15,135,140,None)
        self.makeButton("name8","Back",15,135,210,self.page1)
        
def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x300+50+50')
    script = make(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The error obviously tells you what the issue is.  Go through your code again to see what should be put inside `self.frame_elements`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

was gonna comment but not enough reps, so gonna ask my question here. I copied your script and produced same error too. Firstly its not clear what you want to achieve with script so comments between definitions would help a lot!. When continue button is pressed you want current page to be destroyed and new one to be created right ?

```
enter code here
def frame_elements_remove(self, elements):
    self.elements = elements
    for self.element in self.elements:

        self.element.destroy()
```

To destroy button it has to object. When I try to check for type of element in list ;
self.frame_elements = []

with

```
    def mainPage(self):
    self.frame_elements_remove(self.frame_elements)
    self.makeButton("Button1", "Continue", 10, 10, self.page1)
    self.makeButton("Button2", "Exit", 10, 80, quit)
    self.controler = 1
    self.frame_elements = [self.makeButton]
    #just put here print for type check
    print(type(self.frame_elements[0]))
```

it returns;
<class 'method'>

So its seems, its not destroyable because it is not object but a method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i update the question, i hope its make it clear